# Python Tkinter grid not setup as wanted

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter` in my app and I set a frame with this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import simpledialog

class View:
    def __init__(self,tab):
        self.tab1 = tab

        self.widgets() 

    def proxy_checkbox_clicked(self, event=None):
        if self.proxyVar.get() == 0:
            self.proxyIPTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.proxyPortTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.proxyUserTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.proxyPassTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
        else:
            self.proxyIPTextEdit.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.proxyPortTextEdit.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.proxyUserTextEdit.config(state=NORMAL)
            self.proxyPassTextEdit.config(state=NORMAL)

    def widgets(self):
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.tab1)
        self.mainFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)

        # Set Add Frame
        self.loginFrame = Frame(self.mainFrame)
        self.loginFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 0, pady = 0)

        label = Label(self.loginFrame, text = "Name:")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'W')

        self.nameTextEdit = Entry(self.loginFrame, width = 20)
        self.nameTextEdit.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

        label = Label(self.loginFrame, text = "Phone:")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'W')

        self.phoneTextEdit = Entry(self.loginFrame, width = 20)
        self.phoneTextEdit.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

        self.proxyVar = IntVar()
        self.proxyCheckBox = Checkbutton(self.loginFrame, text="Use Proxy", variable=self.proxyVar, command=self.proxy_checkbox_clicked)
        self.proxyCheckBox.grid(column = 0, row = 2)

        self.proxyFrame = Frame(self.loginFrame)
        self.proxyFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 3)

        label = Label(self.proxyFrame, text = "IP:")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'W')

        self.proxyIPTextEdit = Entry(self.proxyFrame, width = 20)
        self.proxyIPTextEdit.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

        label = Label(self.proxyFrame, text = "Port:")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'W')

        self.proxyPortTextEdit = Entry(self.proxyFrame, width = 20)
        self.proxyPortTextEdit.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

        label = Label(self.proxyFrame, text = "User:")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = 'W')

        self.proxyUserTextEdit = Entry(self.proxyFrame, width = 20)
        self.proxyUserTextEdit.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

        label = Label(self.proxyFrame, text = "Password:")
        label.grid(column = 0, row = 3, sticky = 'W')

        self.proxyPassTextEdit = Entry(self.proxyFrame, width = 20)
        self.proxyPassTextEdit.grid(column = 1, row = 3)

        self.proxyIPTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.proxyPortTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.proxyUserTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.proxyPassTextEdit.config(state=DISABLED)

        self.addButton = Button(self.loginFrame, text="Login", width = 10)
        self.addButton.grid(column = 0, row = 4)
```

When i run it i get this frame, any idea what is the problem? What is missing?
[image]

Comment: The entirety of `proxyFrame` occupies a single column of `loginFrame` - so everything in `loginFrame` with a higher column number is necessarily all the way to the right of `proxyFrame`.  One possibility is to add `columnspan=2` to `proxyFrame`.  Another is to get rid of `proxyFrame` entirely, and have everything in a single grid.

Comment: increase `columnspan` of `proxyframe` to `2`. Like this:  ```proxyFrame.grid(column=0,row=3,columnspan=2)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `self.proxyFrame` fills column 1, of `self.loginFrame`. By definition, anything in column 2 must be to the right of column 1. One simple solution is to have that frame span two columns - both column 1 and column 2. With that, `self.proxyFrame` won't force column 1 to be as wide as the whole frame.

```
self.proxyFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 3, padx=20, pady=20, columnspan=2)
```

As for the checkbutton... widgets by default are centered in the space allocated to them by `grid`. If you want it to be left-aligned, add `sticky="w"` when adding it to the grid.

```
self.proxyCheckBox.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky="w")
```